# implicit conversion for a list of tuple

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I am trying to convert implicitly a `List[(Int, String)]` to `List[(IntWrap, String)]`, which is giving an error of TypeMismatch.

I tried few other conversion which works which are 
`List[Int]` to `List[IntWrap]` and `Tuple2[Int, String]` to `Tuple2[IntWrap, String]` which works.

```
case class IntWrap(a : Int)

implicit def int2IntWrap(x: Int) = IntWrap(x)

implicit def int2IntWrapForTuple2(tuple: Tuple2[Int, String])  = (IntWrap(tuple._1), tuple._2)

//Defined few methods
def foo(t : (IntWrap, String)) = println(t._2)

def foo_list(t: List[IntWrap]) = println(t.size)

def foo_list_tuple(t : List[(IntWrap, String)]) = println(t.size)

foo(3 -> "hello") //this works

foo_list(List(1, 2, 3)) //this works

val l :  List[(IntWrap, String)] = List(3 -> "hello")

foo_list_tuple(l) //this works

val l1 = List(3 -> "hello")
foo_list_tuple(l1) //this one doesn't work
//error: type mismatch; found: List[(Int, String)] required: List[(IntWrap, String)]
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Implicit conversion is evil ...

Answer (score 1):

Try defining implicit conversion like so

```
implicit def listOfTupleToListOfIntWrapTuple(l: List[(Int, String)]): List[(IntWrap, String)] =
  l.map(tuple => (IntWrap(tuple._1), tuple._2))
```

Comment: yes this one works. But I was not sure why this one was working without the explicit List conversion. `val l :  List[(IntWrap, String)] = List(3 -> "hello")`